# zipWithIndex not working as expected in Play! Framework template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using a customer error helper in Play and when using a `map` on the `Seq[FormError]` it works as expected but I'd like to have access to an index so if there are more than x errors I can only show a certain amount.

The working code using `map` is:

```
@form.errors.map { error =>
        @defining(
          error.args.nonEmpty match {
            case true =>
              if (error.key.nonEmpty) {
                error.key + error.args.fold("") ( _ + "." + _ )
              } else {
                error.args.head.toString
              }
            case _ => error.key
          }
        ) { anchor :String =>
              <li class="validation-message" role="tooltip" data-journey="search-page:error:@error.key" id='@anchor.replaceAll("""[\.\[\]]""", "-")-error'>
                <a href="#@anchor" class="error-list" data-focuses="@error.key">
                @Messages(s"$errorMessageFieldPrefix.$anchor")
                </a>
              </li>
          }
      }
```

And the code that doesn't work, using `zipWithIndex` is:

```
@form.errors.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (error, i) =>
    @defining(
      error.args.nonEmpty match {
        case true =>
          if (error.key.nonEmpty) {
            error.key + error.args.fold("") ( _ + "." + _ )
          } else {
            error.args.head.toString
          }
        case _ => error.key
      }
    ) { anchor :String =>
          <li class="validation-message" role="tooltip" data-journey="search-page:error:@error.key" id='@anchor.replaceAll("""[\.\[\]]""", "-")-error'>
            <a href="#@anchor" class="error-list" data-focuses="@error.key">
            @Messages(s"$errorMessageFieldPrefix.$anchor")
            </a>
          </li>
      }
  }
```

Now the error message doesn't show.

Is there some quirk in the framework I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using foreach, which returns unit, in the zipWithIndex variant. Try changing this to map.

Comment: Ah thanks, knew it was something stupid I was doing wrong